# autoprefixer and post css not running on sass files

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I have the following webpack 2.0 rules for css and sass:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      require.resolve('style-loader'),
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: {
          importLoaders: 1
        }
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            autoprefixer({
              browsers: [
                '>1%',
                'last 4 versions',
                'Firefox ESR',
                'not ie < 9' // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
              ],
              flexbox: 'no-2009'
            })
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          query: {
            modules: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            importLoaders: 2,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
          }
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    })
  },
```

How can I get the autoprefixer and postcss to run with the sass files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to add postCSS loader to your sass rule. Something like

```
 {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          query: {
            modules: true,
            sourceMap: true,
            importLoaders: 2,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
          }
        },
        {
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            autoprefixer({
              browsers: [
                '>1%',
                'last 4 versions',
                'Firefox ESR',
                'not ie < 9' // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
              ],
              flexbox: 'no-2009'
            })
          ]
        }
        },
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    })
  },
```

Of course would be nice to define postCSS loader above and reuse in both rules - for .css and .scss